# Finding nearby places using Geocoder - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I'm using geocoder for finding the places near user location . but it gives only longitude / latitude (or nearby places if some places are stored before ). The thing i want to get is when a user puts area name say 'statue of liberty' then result should show places near 'statue of liberty' having a specific tag say 'Hotel'

There is a web having the great implementation of it . You can check it [Here](http://m.rubytuesday.com/)

I'm not asking for full codes snippets rather i'm looking for useful suggestions that how i can make my application work or i have to change my gem . any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To find a `Place` near "statue of liberty" that has the "hotel" `Tag`, it would look like this:

```
Place.near("statue of liberty").where(tags: [:hotel]).all
```

Since you've provided absolutely no information about your schema or models, I've used general names. This is how I have always done it though.

Please refer to the [GeoCoder docs](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) for additional information.

Comment: let me ask a very basic question please . should we have to save all the locations into our database first ? and is there any reference for tag column in the doc because i can not find it

Comment: The tags would need to be setup in your own application. Create a `Tag` model and they should HABTM with `Place`

Comment: dear i have checked the gem and i noticed that it'll find places which are stored in our database only- have i noticed right ?

Comment: Correct. The gem will not find all Hotels in New York unless they are in your database already. GeoCoder isn't Google Maps. Google Maps has its own database of Places.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Geonames_api](https://github.com/buytruckload/geonames_api).

Then You can develop function, and send to it `zipcode`, and `radius` (distance) as the following:

```
def nearby(zipcode, radius)
  GeoNamesAPI.username = "yourusername@yourdomain.com"
  GeoNamesAPI.lang = :en
  geo_name_objects = GeoNamesAPI::NearbyPostalCode.where(country: "US", postalcode: zipcode, radius: radius)
  zip_codes_names = geo_name_objects.postal_codes.map{|h| h.slice("postalCode").values}.flatten.uniq - [zipcode]
end
```

This function will return all zipcodes near by the current zipcode with distance less/equal the exist radius

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `geokit` and `geokit-rails` gems. To use them, you simply need to add `acts_as_mappable :default_units => :kms` (or miles) to the model you want to be able to locate, and then simply use:

Example model: location.rb

```
Location.closest(origin: "statue of liberty")
```

as a normal activerecord query, which can be chained with whatever you want `.where(tags: [:hotel])`.

TIP: geokit uses external geocoders, default is google geocoder, which give timeout errors if called too often. I suggest using Redis to cache geocoding results in a key-value way, such as `$redis[address] = location_id` and have a method that retrieves a location right away if it is in a cache. That way you can greatly lower the risk of geolocation timeout errors.